# How to install ownCloud 8.0.0 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql, owncloud-server

I am following this [link](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html) to install ownCloud in Ubuntu 14.04 and faced following errors.

1. PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server.
2. No database drivers (sqlite, mysql, or postgresql) installed.

In order to resolve this I have followed ownCloud [forum](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=17518) instruction but couldn't resolve.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/586395/edit) your question and add follow information: Is "Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server." a error message you get? What did you do to get that message? What makes you think there are no database drivers installed? Please allways list what command you executed on the command line and what error you received so we can better understand what didn't work and why.

Comment: @MadMike Well I could have given image but it requires 10 reputations to do that.
No. 1 and 2 are the errors I am getting when I am trying to access owncloud from my browser http://localhost/owncloud 
I have given the link of the documentation I am following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `php5-mysql` solved my problem

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
service apache2 restart
```